# numpy arange and where

Tags: python, numpy, where-clause

I am trying to find values in an array created by "arange" by means of "where", but it seems it does not work fine. Here is one example:

```
from numpy import arange, where

myarr = arange(6.6,10.25,0.05)
for item in [6.6,6.65,6.7,6.8,6.9,6.95,7.95,8.0,8.1,8.15,6.2,6.25,6.35]:
 print where(myarr == item)

(array([0]),)
(array([], dtype=int32),)
(array([], dtype=int32),)
(array([], dtype=int32),)
(array([], dtype=int32),)
(array([], dtype=int32),)
(array([], dtype=int32),)
(array([], dtype=int32),)
(array([], dtype=int32),)
(array([], dtype=int32),)
(array([], dtype=int32),)
(array([], dtype=int32),)
(array([], dtype=int32),)
```

Using Python 2.5.4, Numpy 1.3.0

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you want the ouput to be?

Comment: In another array of the same length as myarr

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note:

```
In [32]: repr(myarr[1])
Out[32]: '6.6499999999999995'

In [33]: repr(6.65)
Out[33]: '6.6500000000000004'
```

So the float64 value that `np.arange` assigns to `myarr[1]` is not exactly the same float that Python uses to represent `6.65`.

So, unless you really know what you are doing, [never test floats for equality](http://effbot.org/pyfaq/why-are-floating-point-calculations-so-inaccurate.htm). Use inequalities instead:

```
def near(a,b,rtol=1e-5,atol=1e-8):
    try:
        return np.abs(a-b)<(atol+rtol*np.abs(b))
    except TypeError:
        return False

myarr = np.arange(6.6,10.25,0.05)
for item in [6.6,6.65,6.7,6.8,6.9,6.95,7.95,8.0,8.1,8.15,6.2,6.25,6.35]:
    print (np.where(near(myarr,item)))

# (array([0]),)
# (array([1]),)
# (array([2]),)
# (array([4]),)
# (array([6]),)
# (array([7]),)
# (array([27]),)
# (array([28]),)
# (array([30]),)
# (array([31]),)
# (array([], dtype=int32),)
# (array([], dtype=int32),)
# (array([], dtype=int32),)
```